# Retrieve CDATA section within not well formed XML file and insert them into a SQL table

Tags: sql, xml, xpath, cdata

I'm a newbie at SQL and XML but have to handle this problem for my work...
We have XML files that we need to parse some data into a sql table. 
I found the following T-SQL statement somewhere online which I use to import the xml file into a table( here the table is called xmlimporttest).

```
CREATE TABLE XmlImportTest
(
xmlFileName VARCHAR(300),
xml_data xml
)
GO

DECLARE @xmlFileName VARCHAR(300)
SELECT  @xmlFileName = 'C:\random.xml'
-- dynamic sql is just so we can use @xmlFileName variable in OPENROWSET
EXEC('
INSERT INTO XmlImportTest(xmlFileName, xml_data)

SELECT ''' + @xmlFileName + ''', xmlData
FROM
(
SELECT  * 
FROM    OPENROWSET (BULK ''' + @xmlFileName + ''' , SINGLE_BLOB) AS XMLDATA
) AS FileImport (XMLDATA)
')
GO
SELECT * FROM XmlImportTest



DROP TABLE XmlImportTest
```

The problem here is that the xml file contains CDATA section that cannot be parsed with XPath. I have searched many sql related websites regarding this issue but couldn't find any answers to it. A snapshot of the CDATA section looks like following (It's a mess):

```
 <body>
 &lt;html&gt;
 &lt;head&gt;
 &lt;title&gt;HTML Alert Email&lt;/title&gt;
 &lt;meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Language" content=3D"en-us"&gt;
 &lt;meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dwind=
 ows-1252"&gt;
 &lt;/head&gt;

 &lt;td style=3D"BORDER-LEFT: #C0C0C0 1px solid; BORDER-BOTTOM: #c0c0c0 1p=
 x solid" align=3D"left"&gt;
 &lt;p style=3D"margin-left: 3px; margin-right: 3px"&gt;
 15,000 SF Multi-Family property &lt;/td&gt;
 &lt;td style=3D"BORDER-LEFT: #C0C0C0 1px solid; BORDER-BOTTOM: #c0c0c0 1p=
 x solid" align=3D"left"&gt;
```

Is there a way to retrieve "15,000 SF Multi-Family property" from the xml file using SQL? I'm going to use the same logic to retrieve more data and insert them into a table later.

Comment: This does look like a mess, and I may not understand your requirements correctly (you haven't said how many files, or how many rows to load), but why don't you "fix" the data before you load it into the database. I would suggest using `awk` to extract just the part you need from the file, and load that into your table.